# Difficulty using import/export for two javascript files. getting the: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, game-development

I get the:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
when I try to import/export "class Hero".
Im pretty new in js, and would like to code a game. Im using this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EMxBkqC4z0
as a foundation. I wanted to change it as I need, but got stoped at. the beginning. Tried to find solutions, but anything I found lead me into other problems. Its started from: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Hero'. import call expects exactly one argument. After I fount a solution, it went into "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and... now I don't really know what to do to move on.

Here is the code:

```
1)hero.js 
export default class Hero {

    constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {

        this.width = 150;

        this.height = 20;



        this.position = {

            x: gameWidth / 2 - this.width / 2,

            y: gameHeight - this.height - 10,

        }



    }

    draw(ctx) {

        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";

        ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height)



    }

}

2) index.js 
import { Hero } from "./hero";;



let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");

let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



const GAME_WIDTH = 1280;

const GAME_HEIGHT = 720;



ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1280, 720);



let hero = new Hero(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);



hero.draw(ctx);

3) index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FrogAttack</title>
    <style>
        #gameArea {
            border: 4px solid black;
        }
        
        body {
            height: 100vh;
            background: rgb(2, 0, 36);
            background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(62, 5, 22, 1) 81%, rgba(121, 9, 9, 1) 97%);
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        h1 {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            color: whitesmoke;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Frog Attack</h1>
    <canvas id="gameArea" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import from files in the same directory you have to prepend the filename with `./`, like this:

```js
import Hero from "./hero";
```

Comment: I changed the " import { Hero } from "./hero";" to "import Hero from "./hero";"
But still got the same error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: But now you have put parenthesis around the class name `Hero`. You don't need them when it is a default export. Have a read of this https://sebhastian.com/javascript-import-export/

Comment: Omg thanks a lot, it helped me run the code, and understand import/export way better. Once again thank You very much.